# Getting error when converting string to formatted datetime in powershell "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm retrieving the `Media Created` column field from file explorer this way:

```
$mCreated = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 208);
```

And that works fine. It gives me the string "5/‎7/‎2017 ‏‎4:09 PM"

## The Problem:

When I try to convert the string to formatted date I get this error:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Client\testVideos\anotherTest.ps1:28 char:9
+         $formattedDate = [Datetime]::ParseExact("$mCreated".Trim(), ' ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

## What I've tried:

Tried these individually and all give me the same error:

```
$formattedDate = [Datetime]::ParseExact("$mCreated".Trim(), 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss', $null)
$formattedDate = [Datetime]::ParseExact("$mCreated".Trim(), 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss', [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

# This line actually gives me a different error
$formattedDate = Get-Date "$mCreated".Trim() -Format "yyyyMMddTHHmmss"

# ERROR: Get-Date : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input
```

## What has worked:

I've also been getting the `Created Date` in the same code and formatting it the same way, and it works!

The Created Date is "2/12/2021 1:10 PM", "2/4/2021 3:39 PM", "2/2/2021 9:00 AM", or "2/4/2021 3:54 PM"

```
# This formats it successfully with no error
$createdDate = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 4);
$formattedDate = $createdDate | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddTHHmmss"
```

---

Related but ultimately unhelpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784919/parseexact-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637312/convert-string-to-powershell-datetime

Comment: But it is already a formatted date string. What are you trying to format it to? If you want a true DateTIme Object, just cast it that way.

Comment: My answer assumes you knew `GetDetailsOf()` only returns string values & you were frustrated by casting/conversion to `DateTieme` errors. Is that correct?

Comment: I would also guess the difference between the `Media Created` & `Date Created` strings is that one is a file system property & the other is meta-data. It seems the metadata strings often have "invisible" Unicede characters.

Comment: @KeithMiller Bingo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue in the past with various dates returned by the `Folder.GetDetailsOf()` method. I found the issue to be [Unicode formatting characters](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8207)

```
PS C:\> $TestFile = 'C:\Users\keith\Music\ABBA\Hits\03 Dancing Queen.wma'

>> $ofolder  = $Shell.NameSpace((Split-Path $TestFIle))
>> $oFile    = $oFolder.ParseName((Split-Path $TestFile -Leaf))
>>
>> $MediaCreated = $oFolder.GetDetailsOf($oFile, 208)
>> $MediaCreated
>> $MediaCreated.Length
>> [Int[]][Char[]]$MediaCreated -join '-'
>>
‎6/‎19/‎2010 ‏‎11:54 PM
23
8206-54-47-8206-49-57-47-8206-50-48-49-48-32-8207-8206-49-49-58-53-52-32-80-77
PS C:\>>[DateTime]$MediaCreated
Cannot convert value "‎6/‎19/‎2010 ‏‎11:54 PM" to type "System.DateTime". Error:
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
 + [DateTime]$MediaCreated
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider
```

My solution was to "whitelist" valid DateTime characters in a regualr expression. So the regex matches for  "good" characters are:

- `\w` Any word character (0..9, 'A', 'P', and 'M')
- `\:` Colons (Time separator)
- `/` Slashes (Date separator)
- Spaces

> Separators may vary based on region. I'm hard-coding for U.S. for
> simplicity, brevity, and laziness.

These can be combined & enclosed in brackets to create a [character class](https://regular-expressions.mobi/charclass.html?wlr=1) that will match *valid* characters.:

- `[\w\:/ ]`

To invert the class, & match *invalid* characters, prepend a caret to the class definition:

- `[^\w\:/ ]`

Then we can use the [-Replace operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator)  to remove them:

- **`[DateTime]($MediaCreated -replace '[^\w\:/ ]','')`**

```
PS C:\> $MediaCreated = [DateTime]($MediaCreated -replace '[^\w\:/ ]','')
PS C:\>>$MediaCreated

Saturday, June 19, 2010 11:54:00 PM


PS C:\>>$MediaCreated.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

Just recently learned of the alternative: [**`ShellFolderItem.ExtendedProperty()`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty)

> Gets the value of a property from an item's property set. The property can be specified either by name or by the property set's format identifier (FMTID) and property identifier (PID).
>
> Return value Type: Variant*
>
> When this method returns, contains the value of the property, if it
> exists for the specified item. The value will have full typing—for
> example, dates are returned as dates, not strings.
>
> This method returns a zero-length string if the property is valid but
> does not exist for the specified item, or an error code otherwise.
>
> Remarks There are two ways to specify a property. The first is to
> assign the property's well-known name, such as "Author" or "Date", to
> sPropName. However, each property is a member of a Component Object
> Model (COM) property set and can also be identified by specifying its
> format ID (FMTID) and property ID (PID). An FMTID is a GUID that
> identifies the property set, and a PID is an integer that identifies a
> particular property within the property set.
>
> Specifying a property by its FMTID/PID values is usually more
> efficient than using its name. To use a property's FMTID/PID values
> with ExtendedProperty, they must be combined into an SCID. An SCID is
> a string that contains the FMTID/PID values in the form "FMTID**PID",
> where the FMTID is the string form of the property set's GUID. For
> example, the SCID of the summary information property set's author
> property is "{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9} 4".

I couldn't find the proper name for "Media Created", but the * FMTID/PID* pair is **`"{2E4B640D-5019-46D8-8881-55414CC5CAA0}100"`**:

```
PS C:\>>$oFile.ExtendedProperty("MediaCreated")
PS C:\> $oFile.ExtendedProperty("Media Created")
PS C:\> $oFile.ExtendedProperty("MediaEncoded")
PS C:\> $oFile.ExtendedProperty("MediaCreationDate")
PS C:\> $oFile.ExtendedProperty("System.MediaEncoded")
PS C:\>>$oFile.ExtendedProperty("{2E4B640D-5019-46D8-8881-55414CC5CAA0}100")

Sunday, June 20, 2010 04:54:26 AM


PS C:\>>($oFile.ExtendedProperty("{2E4B640D-5019-46D8-8881-55414CC5CAA0}100")).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

Comment: Will edit & add brief summary.

Comment: Done. Glad I took a second look -- was asble to symplify regex. `\w` includes everything matchned by `\d`, making the latter redundant. I think originally I had the (unnecessarily)more precise `[^\d\:APM/ ]` (in another script).

Comment: `-replace '[^\w\:/ ]',''` did the magic!

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, btw, you could have just done this as well for formatting.

```
($mCreated = (Get-Date -Format g).ToString())
# Results
<#
2/16/2021 11:10 AM
#>

($mCreated).GetType() | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name   BaseType     
-------- -------- ----   --------     
True     True     String System.Object
#>

$mCreated | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition                                                                                                     
----             ----------            ----------                                                                                                     
...                                                                     
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}                                                                                   
Length           Property              int Length {get;} 
#>
```

Cast a date string as datetime object

```
([DateTime]$mCreated = ((Get-Date -Format g).ToString()))
# Results
<#
Tuesday, February 16, 2021 11:12:00 AM
#>

($mCreated).GetType() | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType        
-------- -------- ----     --------        
True     True     DateTime System.ValueType
#>

$mCreated | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
TypeName: System.DateTime

Name                 MemberType     Definition                                                                                                        
----                 ----------     ----------                                                                                                        
...                                                    
ToUniversalTime      Method         datetime ToUniversalTime()                                                                                        
Date                 Property       datetime Date {get;}                                                                                              
Day                  Property       int Day {get;}                                                                                                    
DayOfWeek            Property       System.DayOfWeek DayOfWeek {get;}                                                                                 
DayOfYear            Property       int DayOfYear {get;}                                                                                              
Hour                 Property       int Hour {get;}                                                                                                   
Kind                 Property       System.DateTimeKind Kind {get;}                                                                                   
Millisecond          Property       int Millisecond {get;}                                                                                            
Minute               Property       int Minute {get;}                                                                                                 
Month                Property       int Month {get;}                                                                                                  
Second               Property       int Second {get;}                                                                                                 
Ticks                Property       long Ticks {get;}                                                                                                 
TimeOfDay            Property       timespan TimeOfDay {get;}                                                                                         
Year                 Property       int Year {get;}                                                                                                   
DateTime             ScriptProperty System.Object DateTime {get=if ((& { Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $this.DisplayHint }) -ieq  "Date")... 
#>
```

Details and more here:

- https://adamtheautomator.com/demystifying-powershell-dates-datetime-and-formatting
- https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-conver-string-date-casting/#Converting_a_String_to_a_Date
- http://winpowershell.blogspot.com/2006/09/systemdatetime-parseexact.html#!/2006/09/systemdatetime-parseexact.html
- http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/02/07/parsing-custom-date-and-time-formats.aspx

As far as a string with parseexact. It is impacted by how your system date is set up and that yeat must be at the beginning or end of the timestamp. See the details here:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("20181010134412",'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)
# Results
<#
Wednesday, October 10, 2018 1:44:12 PM
#>

($mCreated).GetType() | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name   BaseType     
-------- -------- ----   --------     
True     True     String System.Object
#>

[datetime]::ParseExact($mCreated,'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)
[datetime]::ParseExact($($mCreated),'yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)
# Results
<#
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
#>

$mCreated
# Results
<#
2/16/2021 11:24 AM
#>

[datetime]::ParseExact('20210216112400','yyyyMMddHHmmss',$null)
[datetime]::ParseExact('02161124002021','MMddHHmmssyyyy',$null)
# Results
<#
Tuesday, February 16, 2021 11:24:00 AM
Tuesday, February 16, 2021 11:24:00 AM
#>
```

Or you end up here:

```
$mCreated = '16/02/2021 9:11 AM'
([datetime]::ParseExact($mCreated,'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt',$null))
$mCreated = '02/16/2021 9:11 AM'
([datetime]::ParseExact($mCreated,'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt',$null))
# Results
<#
Tuesday, February 16, 2021 9:11:00 AM
Tuesday, February 16, 2021 9:11:00 AM
#>
```

See the details here:

- https://lazywinadmin.com/2018/10/PowerShellTip-DateTimeParsing.html

Unprintable/invisible characters is the issue when trying to use the date string from the call.

```
$FileInformation    = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'F:\Videos\2020 03 19 Competitive Intel.mp4'
$ShellApplication   = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

$ShellFolder        = $ShellApplication.Namespace($FileInformation.Directory.FullName)
$ShellFile          = $ShellFolder.ParseName($FileInformation.Name)

$MetaDataProperties = [ordered] @{}

0..400 | 
ForEach-Object -Process {
    $DataValue     = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_)
    $PropertyValue = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($DataValue.Trim()).Replace(' ', '')

    if ($PropertyValue -ne '') 
    {$MetaDataProperties["$_"] = $PropertyValue}
}

$MetaDataProperties.Values -Match 'media'
# Results
<#
MediaCreated
#>

###
($MediaCreated = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile , 208))
($DateCreated  = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile , 4))
($MediaCreated).GetType()
($DateCreated).GetType()
# Results
<#
19-‎Mar-‎20 ‏‎17:30
03-Dec-20 13:05

IsPublic IsSerial Name    BaseType
-------- -------- ----    --------
True     True     String  System.Object
True     True     String  System.Object
#>


($TestDate = Get-Date(Date) -Format g) 
($TestDate1 = Get-Date(Date) -Format g) -replace '-|\s|:'
# Results
<#
17-Feb-21 16:41
17Feb211641
#>

([datetime]::ParseExact($TestDate,'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm',$null))
([datetime]::ParseExact($TestDate1,'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm',$null))
# Results
<#
Wednesday, 17 February, 2021 16:54:00
Wednesday, 17 February, 2021 16:54:00
#>

(('17-Feb-21 16:41').ToCharArray()).Count
# Results
<#
15
#>


([datetime]::ParseExact($MediaCreated,'dd-MMM-yy HH:mm',$null))
# Results
<#
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized 
as a valid DateTime."
#>
```

In regular cmd.exe (not cmd.exe from PowerShell (ISE/consolehost) or via Windows Terminal), there are unprintable/invisible characters that do not appear in Notepad/consolehost/ISE/VSCode/Windows Terminal.

[image]

```
(($MediaCreated).ToCharArray()).Count
# Results
<#
20  # multiple hidden/non-printable characters
#>

($MediaCreated).ToCharArray() 
# Results
<#
1
9
-
‎
M
a
r
-
‎
2
0

‏
‎
1
7
:
3
0 

#>

(($MediaCreated).ToCharArray())[0]
(($MediaCreated).ToCharArray())[1]
(($MediaCreated).ToCharArray())[2]
(($MediaCreated).ToCharArray())[3]
# Results
<#
1
9
-

#>

($MediaCreated).ToCharArray() | 
ForEach{ [int][char]$PSItem }
# Results
<#
8206
49
57
45
8206
77
97
114
45
8206
50
48
32
8207
8206
49
55
58
51
48
#>
```

Hence why Keiths' regex works...

```
([datetime]::ParseExact(($MediaCreated -replace '[^\w\:/ ]'),'ddMMMyy HH:mm',$null))
# Results
<#
Thursday, 19 March, 2020 17:30:00
#>
```

... and thus we can go get this more directly, to allow parseexact to work, and not have to change the data type:

```
$FileInformation  = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'F:\Videos\2020 03 19 Competitive Intel.mp4'
$ShellApplication = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

$ShellFolder      = $ShellApplication.Namespace($FileInformation.Directory.FullName)
$ShellFile        = $ShellFolder.ParseName($FileInformation.Name)

($MediaCreated    = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile , 208))
($DateCreated     = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile , 4))
# Results
<#
‎19-‎Mar-‎20 ‏‎17:30
03-Dec-20 13:05
#>

($MediaCreated).GetType()
($DateCreated).GetType()

# Results
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType     
-------- -------- ----     --------     
True     True     String   System.Object
True     True     String   System.Object 
#>        

([datetime]::ParseExact(($MediaCreated -replace '[^\w\:/ ]'),'ddMMMyy HH:mm',$null))
([datetime]::ParseExact(($DateCreated -replace '[^\w\:/ ]'),'ddMMMyy HH:mm',$null))
# Results
<#

Thursday, 19 March, 2020 17:30:00
Thursday, 3 December, 2020 13:05:00
#>

($MediaCreated).GetType()
($DateCreated).GetType()
# Results
<#

IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType     
-------- -------- ----     --------     
True     True     String   System.Object
True     True     String   System.Object 
#>
```

Comment: Ditto on Keith's answer and I started down that regex path but decided not to do that and try to go at it another way. Agreed, regarding the [datetime]::ParseExact. Yep, I coded that split and seconds append thing. The date ToStirng thing was just to get a date string from a source, vs manually typing in a string. Not really a conversion use case. Yet, that is the reason for the links, since several things impact the string date use case.